# How to inject with multiple statements disabled?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

Suppose the website is written in PHP which disables multiple statements. If the query looks like this:

```
Select id From TableX Where num = >userInput<
```

Is it impossible to Update or Delete record by SQL Injection? Is it possible to get the content from another table, like tableB, which may not be union-compatible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

userInput = `-1 union select GetCharCode(SomeStringField, CharPosition) from SomeTable where SomeCondition`, where `GetCharCode` returns the code of character in `CharPosition` of `SomeStringField` (you need to write some DB-specific code there) will help you to get the value of `SomeStringField` by looping through possible `CharPosition`s, and thus bypass the problem of tableB not being "union-compatible".

Comment: What do you means by code of character? Moreover, isn't this just return the same number of columns as before? How did the two tables become union compatible now?

Comment: @FiniteA, i mean the ASCII code. You can get the first character of the field of your interest (substituting the `CharPosition` of 1), then get the second character etc.

Comment: So you mean it will combine the first character of every columns into single string? which matches the single column in the query "Select id from..."? Then I wonder how in general you can apply this trick if there are multiple columns in the first part of query, say "Select id1, id2 from ..."

Comment: I mean that you can get the needed data by requesting it char-by-char, with a new query for each needed field and each needed character in this field.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious about questions like "How to inject", "How to break in", "How to steal some info", implying getting step by step instructions - are such questions welcome on this site or not?

Comment: Some people want to know points where their application is at risk.

Comment: they know their points for sure. The point explicitly marked in the question.